# Linq to SQL insert - ID not incrementing

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I am learning MVC2 and I am trying to create a data request management system. Somewhat like a ticketing system. A quick question, in my mvc controller class I have a post-create

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Request request)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                var db = new DB();
                db.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(request);

                db.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(request);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return View(request);
        }

    }
```

Ok, this is extremely simple enough, well I add my view and once I create a row I get the 0 first in my Primary Key row. Then it will not increment anymore, I goto add another row and the catch returns me to the same view I am on. It seems that the primary key int id is not incrementing.

How do you auto increment the id (type int) here? I am a bit confused why MVC isn't handling this since it is the primary key type int. It will only make the first row with the id = 0 and that's all.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an MVC problem to me - what database technology are you using?

Comment: @central - I edited the tags on your question from asp.net-mvc to linq-to-sql because your question and it's cause is at the database level.  Btw - you need to mark the ID column in your table as IDENTITY(1,1) - or open up SSMS and set the Identity flag in there.

Comment: Currently to develop I am using SQL Express with only the Server Explorer in VS2010 to handle. And Thanks Andras Zoltan that is a linq to sql tag. Makes sense about the identity tag, going to figure it out right now in VS.

-edit . Easy enough under Column Properties in VisualStudio's 2k10, 'Identity Specification' -- (is Identity) is changed to 'Yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID column needs to be set as an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column in the table in SQL server.

Also you should create your `DB` data context in a `using`:

```
using(var db = new DB())
{
  db.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(request); 

  db.SubmitChanges(); 
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

Otherwise you're spilling connections all over the place; and creating more memory leaks than an early build of windows (well, depending on your traffic ;) )

Comment: Thank you for help, 'using' is crucial then. But I have adjusted to a identity column and currently I am still hitting the same create-View. Will keep trying to get things working and post back.

Comment: So what I did was delete the .dbml from my model that was connecting to the database. Made changes to the identity, and recreated the Linq to Sql class and it works fine now.

Comment: Ah yes, it was the auto-generated value property on that column in the dbml: makes it re-read the value back after insert